# Creating a short fur material in Blender

Tags: materials, procedural

In the Blue Sky Studios movie Ferdinand, I learned that the body fur on the bull characters was created using a material that emulates very short fur. How can I create a material like that in Blender?

[image: Article]

Comment: hello maybe show a close-up picture of this fur?

Comment: @moonboots https://www.cgw.com/Publications/CGW/2018/Volume-41-Issue-1-Edition-1-2018-/Gentle-Giant.aspx

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please avoid text written inside images, always prefer typing it directly in the body of the post instead. Image content can't be indexed and thus can't be readily found when searching in the future. Updates are difficult because it can't be easily edited in case of mistakes, nor updated in case of future changes. It doesn't follow the fonts and style of the website automatically, and doesn't work with screen readers.

Comment: Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Answer (score 0):

You could stretch a *Noise Texture* on the surface of your character, and plug this noise into the *Base Color*, the *Specular* and the *Normal* inputs of your *Principled BSDF*, in order to have 2 hair colors, a variation in the reflectivity, and a bit of bump:

[image]